# How can we easily time function calls in elixir?

Tags: function, timing, elixir

How can we easily ***time*** function calls in Elixir?

Is there any hidden switch in IEx to enable this?

Comment: I don't think there's an option to do that. Probably the easier and quickest way to do that is Erlang's [`timer:tc/1-2-3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1).

Comment: @whatyouhide not sure what i'm doing wrong

`iex(54)> :timer.tc(Demo.sum 1000)
** (BadFunctionError) expected a function, got: 500500
    (stdlib) timer.erl:165: :timer.tc/1`

Comment: as you can see in the documentation for `timer:tc/1` I linked in the previous comment, if you're only passing one argument to `timer:tc` it has to be a function. Your example would be `:timer.tc(fn -> Demo.sum(1000) end)`. If you want to pass a module+function+arguments triplet, just go with `:timer.tc(Demo, :sum, [1000])`.

Comment: @whatyouhide thanks

:timer.tc(Demo, :sum, [1000])

Comment: @whatyouhide your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can write a module<sup>1</sup> that can measure a given function. The following function returns the runtime of a given function in seconds:

```
defmodule Benchmark do
  def measure(function) do
    function
    |> :timer.tc
    |> elem(0)
    |> Kernel./(1_000_000)
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
iex> Benchmark.measure(fn -> 123456*654321 end)
9.0e-6
```

If you want to use that for Benchmarking, then there is another answer.

A better approach than measuring single run execution time is to measure operations per timeframe. This takes the code under test and executes it repeatingly within a given timeframe. This methodology yields more accurate results.

There is a library called [Benchwarmer](https://github.com/mroth/benchwarmer) you can use for that:

Add Benchwarmer to your `mix.exs`

```
def deps do
  [ { :benchwarmer, "~> 0.0.2" } ]
end
```

Simply pass an inline function:

```
iex> Benchwarmer.benchmark fn -> 123456*654321 end
*** #Function<20.90072148/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5> ***
1.2 sec     2M iterations   0.61 μs/op

[%Benchwarmer.Results{...}]
```

- [1]: Code taken from http://www.littlelines.com/blog/2014/06/27/elixir-vs-ruby-showdown-part-one/
- Benchee https://github.com/bencheeorg/benchee

Comment: Thanks, would be nice to have this build into the Iex tool.

Comment: What is the unit of time that function |> :timer.tc |> elem(0) |> Kernel./(1_000_000) returns? Is it microseconds?

Comment: Benchwarmer version should be "~> 0.0.2" or installing dependencies will fail.

Comment: @SashaFonseca it's in seconds, since `timer.tc` returns microseconds.

Comment: The Hex docs for IEx say:

"The first one is that the code is truly evaluated and not compiled. This means that any benchmarking done in the shell is going to have skewed results. So never run any profiling nor benchmarks in the shell."

Does this apply to these kind of imported libraries? Aka is this actually a realistic benchmark?

Comment: So the code above can be taken to compile and run a realistic benchmark. I will update the answer, so that I do not use iex for running the example.

Answer (score 18):

This is an answer to a 6 year old question. But I ran into this topic while searching for such a capability and the module suggestion implies one can do:

```
{time, your_func_result} = :timer.tc(&your_func/arity, [your_func-args])
```

Thought I would drop that here in case someone else ended up searching for this. After all it's Erlang underneath. So you don't have to define another function in a module etc. time is in microseconds.

Comment: Well, Overbird included this solution in his answer.