# Composing Task.async_stream vs. Continuation passing

Tags: concurrency, task, elixir

I have a pipeline of two functions that are both IO-heavy, running on a collection of items concurrently.

The first, `func1`, is very common, and often I just want the response of `func1` alone. Other times, I'd like to process the result of `func1` with some other function, `func2`.

What are the trade-offs (performance/overhead, idiomatic-ness) between composing Task.async_stream, i.e.

```
enum
|> Task.async_stream(Mod1, :func1, [])
|> Task.async_stream(Mod2, :func2, [])
...
```

vs. passing a continuation and using one Task.async_stream for both `func1` and `func2` i.e.

```
enum
|> Task.async_stream(Mod1, :func1_then, [&Mod2.func2/arity])
...
```

where `func1_then` calls the function parameter (`Mod2.func2`) at the end of the normal `func1` computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both functions are IO bound, then there shouldn't be any problem with your first example:

```
enum
|> Task.async_stream(Mod1, :func1, [])
|> Task.async_stream(Mod2, :func2, [])
```

If you did want to collapse the two calls, I wouldn't use a continuation style, just pipeline them in a lambda passed to [Task.async_stream/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/3):

```
enum
|> Task.async_stream(fn x -> x |> Mod1.func1() |> M2.func2() end)
```

Alternatively, you might consider using [Flow](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html#content):

```
enum 
|> Flow.from_enumerable()
|> Flow.map(&Mod1.func1/1)
|> Flow.map(&Mod2.func2/1)
|> Flow.run()
```

Comment: Great answer, glad to have more perspectives on the way to accomplish this. Does flow introduce additional overhead over Task.async_stream? The two functions are IO bound (reading/writing files), but the collection itself is typically going to be less than 100 items.

Comment: To follow up on this, I did some **very naive** benchmarking (using example found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29674651/1492117)) and found that in 500 runs of each, the average times were as follows:

`Composed Task.async: 0.204734s`
`Piped Task.async: 0.21415s`
`Flow: 0.25598s`

Obviously to be taken with a grain of salt for any other context.

Comment: First example is better than second one, because you split functions into two different streams, in second example you have only one stream hence operations aren't that isolated on the very same level.