# Elixir: sum 2+ digit number

Tags: elixir

I'm studying functional programming with Elixir and came across the following exercise:

> "You are given a two-digit integer n. Return the sum of its digits."

The solution I came up looks a bit "hairy".
I wonder if someone could give some advice into Elixir std lib functions/module and provide a better solution.
I know I could just go with `n%10 + Math.floor(n/10)`(js) but Id' like to know if a solution using Elixir functions would be more or less what I came up with:

```
def addTwoDigits(n) do
   n |> Integer.to_string 
     |> String.split("") # Number 44 would give a list ["",4,4,""]
     |> Enum.filter(&(&1 != ""))
     |> Enum.map(&(String.to_integer(&1)))
     |> Enum.reduce(&(&1+&2))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest and closest to your initial thought, would be by leveraging the following function:

```
Integer.digits(123)
[1, 2, 3]
```

to obtain each individual digit as documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#digits/2)

You can then simply do:

```
def sum_digits_in_number(n) do
   n
   |> Integer.digits
   |> Enum.sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **avoid unnecessary operations** (conversion to string, conversion to list, etc.).

I'd go with the following, using [**`div/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#div/2) & [**`rem/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#rem/2) in a recursive function:

```rb
def addTwoDigits(n) do
  if n > 0, do: rem(n, 10) + addTwoDigits(div(n, 10)), else: n
end
```

---

I used [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668635/how-can-we-easily-time-function-calls-in-elixir#29674651) to compare our functions:

- your function runs in ~16 μs
- the function above runs in ~4 μs

**By working with integers you avoid useless conversions/iterations** & get a function that computes your result ~4 times faster!

Comment: Be careful of premature optimization.  How important is a factor of 4 speed improvement on learning code that someone's doing to learn FP?

Answer (score 1):

Since it’s an exercise / learning example, I would assume the answer expected would be a function with many clauses:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def add(num, acc \\ 0)
  def add(num, _acc) when num > 99, do: raise("Invalid #{num}")
  def add(num, acc) when num < 10, do: acc + num
  def add(num, acc), do: add(rem(num, 10), acc + div(num, 10))
end

IO.puts M.add(35)
#⇒ 8
IO.puts M.add(5)
#⇒ 5
IO.puts M.add(88)
#⇒ 16
IO.puts M.add(101)
#⇒ ** (RuntimeError) Invalid 101
```

This is definitely a huge overkill for this particular task, but think how easy is to make this code to sum integers having 3 numbers (unlike any other non-functional approach.)