# Elixir: cannot run :timer.tc in spawned process in elixir script

Tags: elixir

That works fine in iex console:

`iex(1)> spawn(fn -> :timer.tc(:timer, :sleep, [100]) |> elem(0) |> IO.puts end)
 #PID<0.106.0>
 100603`

But when I put exactly the same line `spawn(fn -> :timer.tc(:timer, :sleep, [100]) |> elem(0) |> IO.puts end)` inside .exs script - nothing happens, no output at all.

Why is that? How can I measure function's execute time in parallel?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in parallel? And how it supposed to work? Why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29674651/2501279) approach is not suitable for you?

Comment: @GuruStron why OP needs to do it in parallel is completely out of the scope of the original question. Also, benchmarks and telemetry have absolutely different applications, and this question is surely more about [`telemetry`](https://hexdocs.pm/telemetry/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script exits before this gets printed *and* you do not monitor the started process, which results in kinda race condition. In fact, everything works as expected. Make sure your script waits for the spawned process to finish (the proper way would be use [`Task`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html), but this is OK for PoC:

```rb
# test.exs
spawn(fn ->
  :timer
  |> :timer.tc(:sleep, [100])
  |> elem(0)
  |> IO.puts()
end)
Process.sleep(1_000)
```

---

Proper solution:

```rb
# test.exs
task = Task.async(fn ->
  :timer
  |> :timer.tc(:sleep, [100])
  |> elem(0)
  |> IO.puts()
end)
Task.await(task) # this prevents ErlangVM from immediate exit
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that works :) 
Now I can spawn several processes, save to list and run Task.await on every task.

Comment: Of course, it works. To await several tasks one might use [`Task.yield_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/2) instead.